# react context value undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-context

I am following a tutorial, and i'm having an issue with react context

I have my context component that looks like this

```
import React from 'react'

export const firebaseAuth = React.createContext()

const AuthProvider = props => {
  const { children } = props
  return (
    <firebaseAuth.Provider
      value={{
        test: 'context is working',
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </firebaseAuth.Provider>
  )
}

export default AuthProvider
```

And I am trying to test my context inside of my `Router` component, unfortunately `test` is undefined and i'm not sure how to debug it

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import AuthProvider, { firebaseAuth } from './database/provider/AuthProvider'

const Router = () => {
  const test = useContext(firebaseAuth)
  console.log(test)
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login/" component={SignIn} />
   
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default Router
```

I know this question has been asked a bunch of time on here, and I have looked at those threads and still cannot find a solution.

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a value from context, there needs to be a provider somewhere higher up the component tree. So anything that's a *descendant* of `<AuthProvider>` can call `useContext(firebaseAuth)` and see `{test: 'context is working'}`. But `Router` is outside of `<AuthProvider>`, so it will only get the default value, which in your case is undefined.

Comment: Oh ok, I see now. So I need an additional `Provider` that wraps around `Router`?

Comment: While there are cases where multiple providers make sense, your auth provider should almost certainly be a singleton. So rather than adding a provider, you need to move the existing one farther up the component tree.